# 403 Forbidden message in SharePoint after deploying App Part for Anonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I'm Building High-Trust Application for SharePoint on Premises for a Public Facing Internet Site.
I've Created an Empty App Part and deploy it to the SharePoint. The App Part is Working fine for authenticated users but when try to access the site as anonymous I'm Receiving "403 Forbidden Error Message".
This is Although I can access the page that is displayed in the App Part anonymously without any Problem.

Update:The Problem is only in the page that has the App Part. other SharePoint pages are working fine even anonymously.

Can any one support in this.

Answer (score 0):

That's mean the host web is not allowed for anonymous users. You could double check the authentication for the anonymous user on the host web.